Determining the xy-limits of Weibull plot by matplotlib using reliability package in Python
The issue is that I have an exercise which is to evaluate the time at 1% (0.01). I cannot see this percentge on the y-axis. I need to change the limits. My code is the following:
from reliability.Distributions import Weibull_Distribution
from reliability.Fitters import Fit_Weibull_2P

# The data is already sorted. Thereby we can generate the weibull distributions
wb1 = Fit_Weibull_2P(failures=FC1_1uA_cleaned, show_probability_plot=True)
wb2 = Fit_Weibull_2P(failures=FC2_5uA_cleaned, show_probability_plot=True)
wb3 = Fit_Weibull_2P(failures=FC3_25uA_cleaned, show_probability_plot=True)

# We can plot it now by matplot lib
plt.ylabel('Unreliability [%]')
plt.xlim(5,35)
#plt.ylim(0.01, 100)
plt.show()

I use Spyder IDE
I have tried using plt.ylim, but it causes error in all the plots. I hope someone can explain to me how it should be changedenter image description here
